# Get link from database and display it (like facebook link)

Tags: php, facebook, hyperlink, embed

I am creating a facebook - style site, but have hit a brick wall when getting a link and if it is a youtube video, display it as an embeded youtube video.

Basically - if a database value contains the link:  http://www.youtube.com/foo it embeds that like facebook does.

THIS IS **NOT** Facbebook API and I don't mind how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: @Repox I have tried to find the actual hyperlink but have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone submits a YouTube URL, use YouTube's JavaScript API to embed the player.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Functions

You'll probably want to use `cueVideoByUrl()`.

To locate a YouTube URL within user input, probably the easiest thing to do is to create a regular expression to find it.  This can be complicated if you allow HTML tags in user input etc., but if you've correctly sanitized the user input and are not allowing tags or special characters, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: But how can I extract the youtube link from a bunch of other texts?

Comment: Minimal effort would probably be to use a regular expression to locate YouTube URLs from the user input.  (I'll amend my answer to mention that.)